# Compile for release

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, release, sdl

I was writing a simple pong application and while its not finished I'd lie to be able to figure out how to compile it for release. I get no errors and i linked against SDL, SDLmain,SDL_image,SDL_ttf but when people on other computers try to run it (both the debug and release) it closes as if it's missing files. I put SDL.dll,SDL_image.dll, SDL-ttf.dll all in there along with the images i use in the program, it works fine on my computer so that says theres a file I'm missing for it...but what would that be?

EDIT:

Finally after 30 minutes i figured it out: when including SDL_image.dll you also have to include SDL_image.dll's dependencies : zlib1.dll,libjjpeg-x.dll,libpng..etc

Comment: Use something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine which DLL files your app needs.

Comment: Thats a very useful program, but apparently this isn't my issue. so you indeed got me closer by narrowing out possibility that i left out a dll.

Comment: i wish you would have put that as an answer I would have +1 it

Comment: Welcome to DLL hell, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to solve this sort of problem (if it's DLL related) is to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). This will show you all the dependencies of an executable, and the dependencies of the dependencies.

If you run it on the target platform, it will highlight DLLs that are required but not available, making it easier to see why your executable won't run.